# Limit number of applications in WSO2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 api manager.In that,is it possible to limit number of applications that can be created by a tenant or an user in devportal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default limit of applications getting listed in devportal is 25. You can still create new applications beyond 25, but they won't get listed in UI, unless you delete the earlier ones.

To completely disallow user to create new applications once the preferred limit is exceeded, disabling the `Add new application` button once the limit is exceeded together with a warning message will resolve.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it is not possible to limit the number of applications that can be created. One possible way is  to achieve it with the UI customization. [Devportal REST API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#tag/Applications/paths/%7E1applications/get) - `GET /applications` can be used to retrieve all the application details. The response of this resource looks like:

```json
{
  "count": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "applicationId": "xxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited",
      "description": "",
      "status": "APPROVED",
      "groups": "",
      "subscriptionCount": 0,
      "attributes": "",
      "owner": "admin"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 1,
    "total": 10,
    "next": "",
    "previous": ""
  }
}
```

You can disable the `Add new application` button from UI, if the **total** number of application exceeds the value you want.